# Discord Rewrite Bot crashed after uploading to heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

It used to work fine so far both in heroku and locally. Now it only works locally but doesn't work aftter deploying on heroku. This is the log from Heroku:

```
2021-05-11T14:24:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-11T14:24:06.163275+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-05-11T14:24:15.306244+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-05-11T14:24:15.306768+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/dbot.py", line 2, in <module>
2021-05-11T14:24:15.307297+00:00 app[worker.1]: import discord
2021-05-11T14:24:15.307369+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
2021-05-11T14:24:15.307970+00:00 app[worker.1]: from .client import *
2021-05-11T14:24:15.307996+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 36, in <module>
2021-05-11T14:24:15.308464+00:00 app[worker.1]: from .user import User
2021-05-11T14:24:15.308533+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/user.py", line 26, in <module>
2021-05-11T14:24:15.309148+00:00 app[worker.1]: import discord.abc
2021-05-11T14:24:15.309214+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 101, in <module>
2021-05-11T14:24:15.309876+00:00 app[worker.1]: SnowflakeTime = Union[Snowflake, datetime]
2021-05-11T14:24:15.310045+00:00 app[worker.1]: NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
2021-05-11T14:24:15.685219+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-11T14:24:15.995755+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I have my requirments.txt file with these dependencies included:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
youtube_dl==2020.03.08
pynacl == 1.3.0
colorlog == 4.1.0
```

And I have this in my procfile:

```
worker: python dbot.py
```

I know that it says 'datetime' is not defined but here is the first few lines from my main python file:

```
import datetime
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
import random
import youtube_dl
import os
from discord.utils import get
import ctypes
import ctypes.util
```

As for my knowledge, it all started after i added the following event to my codes:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    try:
        if ctx.channel.name == "memes" and "https://" not in str(ctx.content) and not ctx.attachments:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        else:
            await client.process_commands(ctx)
    except:
            await client.process_commands(ctx)
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined`: is datetime installed for python-3.9 on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py` is the development branch of discord.py, do not use it in production.

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@1.7.2
```

1.7.2 is the latest version.

Or from PyPi

```
discord.py>=1.7.2
```

discord.py is available in PyPI, and hence can be directly downloaded from PyPI.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is the correct one that is causing that error, but what you showed for your on_message event is also incorrect. I recommend reading [the documentation for on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) to see how it is supposed to work.

EDIT:

It is currently working because you aren't using anything that uses the `Context` object. `on_message` takes a `discord.Message` parameter, not a `commands.Context` parameter. This means that if you try to use a method or attribute from `Context`, it won't work because `Message` is the parameter passed to `on_message`.

For example, if I tried to do `ctx.bot` in your code, it would give me an error because `discord.Message` does not have a bot attribute. Now you might be looking at the docs and wondering why it says `ctx` has a bot attribute, but it is erroring when you try it. For this reason I recommend changing your `on_message` parameter to be called `message` and change all instances of `ctx` to `message` to avoid later confusion.